# How to read attributes in LWC when using $Lightning.createComponent

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass the recordId as an attribute to a lightning web component used in a visual force page. However, I am struggling to find how I read the attributes set in the $Lightning.createComponent, nothing seems to get passed through to the constructor.

The documentation around this seems to be non-existent, I guess this is something they don't want you to do, but unfortunately I need to.

Any help much appreciated.

The code in the vfp is

```
    $Lightning.use('c:CRLightningWrapper', function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
            'c:collectionsContainer',
            {
                recordId: "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"
            },
            'collectionsContainer',
            function(cmp) {
                console.log('component created {!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}');
        });
    });
```

I am following the documentation and implement in the lwc like below:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class Record extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Account.Name'] })
    record;
}
```

Comment: Is your aura component receiving the record id ? Can tou share the relevant parts of your aura and lwc components?

Comment: The component is a lightning web component wrapped in an aura:application. My LWC is implemented as edit above, but the recordId doesn't appear to get passed in as the getRecord fails to return the record.

Comment: last I checked LWC's are not supported in lightning:out apps

Comment: Coming in Summer 19 by the looks of it :
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_lwc_vf.htm?edition=&impact=

Comment: Are you on Summer 19 and can you share your component meta file?

Comment: The above code did actually work and my issue was further down the chain. Currently working on sandbox with Summer 19 patch 4 on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually is documented, it is just very well hidden: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/data_get_user_input

To summarise, in your Lightning Web Component you need to make sure you import *api* and expose the *recordId* property:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement{
    // Expose a recordId property.
    @api recordId;
}
```

Additionally, change the following line in your VisualForce Page:

```
recordId: "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"
```

to

```
record-id: "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"
```

Comment: Thanks, @koen-wesselman, this is the approach I tried but the recordId value appears to be null. I was following [data_wire_service_about](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about)

Comment: Ah, fair enough @sdelaney79.. Shot in the dark: Can you try changing recordId: "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" to record-id: "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}" ?

Comment: Will give it a go and let you know how I get on

Answer (score 0):

> **caveat:Considering the org you are using is not Summer '19 preview**

After seeing the post I got curious and tested couple of things,

**Testing by passing string:**
I am passing  the `$CurrentPage.parameters.id` to String attribute in Aura Component and passed that to Lightning web component public property `accountId` and the value is getting passed.Check the code below:

**VF Page**

```
    <apex:page standardcontroller="Account" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" class="slds"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $Lightning.use("c:lwcapp", function() {
           $Lightning.createComponent(
                  "c:accountIdtolwccmp",
                       {
                        accountId: "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}"
                       },
                  "lightning",
                 function(cmp) {
                 console.log('component created');
               });
             });
       </script>
      </apex:page>
```

**accountIdtolwccmp**

```
     <aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
     <aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String" />
     <lightning:card title="Account Id Section in Aura" iconName="custom:custom14">
         Account Id in Aura:{!v.accountId} 
     </lightning:card>
     <c:passaccountidtolwc accountId="{!v.accountId}"/>
     </aura:component>
```

**passaccountidtolwc**

```
      <template>
       <lightning-card title="Account Id Section in LWC" icon-name="custom:custom14">
         <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
            AccountIdinLWC:{accountId}</br>
         </div>
       </lightning-card>
       </template>

       import { LightningElement,api} from 'lwc';
        export default class Lwcrec extends LightningElement {
           @api accountId;
        }
```

**Testing lightning/ui*Api Wire Adapter with recordId and string accountId property:**
    If I pass the `recordId` to the `ui*Api getrecord Adapter` it failed to return any value.But If I pass the `accountId` which I pass from aura component to the adapter it return the account values.check the below code:

**Template**

```
        <template>
        <lightning-card title="Account Id Section in LWC" icon-name="custom:custom14">
          <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
          AccountIdinLWC:{accountId}</br>
          AccountNamebasedonuiApiAdaptor:{name}
        </div>
        </lightning-card>
        </template>
```

**JS**

```
   import { LightningElement,api,wire,track} from 'lwc';
   import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
   export default class Lwcrec extends LightningElement {
   @api accountId;
   @api recordId;
   @track record;
   @track name;
   @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$accountId', fields: ['Account.Name'] })
   wiredRec({ error, data }) {
     if (data) {
         this.record = data;
         console.log('record---'+JSON.stringify(this.record));
         console.log(this.record.fields.Name.value);
         this.name=this.record.fields.Name.value;
         this.error = undefined;
      } else if (error) {
         this.error = error;
         this.record = undefined;
          }
        }
     }
```

**Conclusion**

Either you can wait for the feature **Use Lightning Web Components in Visual force Pages in Summer 19**.Or you can try passing the String from the Visual force page use it in the **ui*Api getrecord Adapter**.